# Real time updating in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I would like to build a d3 layout which continually gathers new data and updates the visualization accordingly.  Here is a working prototype of what I have in mind (with randomly generated data):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script src="d3/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="application/javascript">

var width = window.innerWidth;
var height = window.innerHeight;

var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var layout;
iterateLayout(svg, 0);

function iterateLayout(svg, counter) {
    if(counter % 3 == 0)
        layout = generateLayout(20);
    else if(counter % 3 == 1)
        layout = generateLayout(100);
    else
        layout = generateLayout(500);

    layout.force.start();
    console.log("Force computations begin");

    layout.force.on("end", function() {
        console.log("Force computations complete");
        displayLayout(svg, layout);
        console.log("Layout should be visible, starting next layout computation");
        iterateLayout(svg, counter + 1);
    });
}

function generateLayout(numNodes) {
    var nodes = [];
    var links = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < numNodes; i++)
        nodes.push({"name": i});

    var index;

    for(var i = 0; i < numNodes; i++)
        for(var j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            index = Math.floor((Math.random() * numNodes));

            if(i != index)
                links.push({"source": i, "target": index});
        }

    var force = d3.layout.force()
        .size([width, height])
        .nodes(nodes)
        .links(links);

    return {"force": force, "nodes": nodes, "links": links};
}

function displayLayout(svg, layout) {
    svg.selectAll("*").remove();

    var links = svg.selectAll(".link")
        .data(layout.links)
        .enter()
        .append("line")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .style("stroke", "black");

    var nodes = svg.selectAll(".node")
        .data(layout.nodes)
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("r", 4)
        .style("fill", "black");

    links
        .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    nodes
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
}
</script>
```

This code behaves exactly the way I want, except for the fact that it depends on infinite recursive calls of the `iterateLayout` function.  Aside from the fact that this is a memory leak, this means that the code will eventually consume the browser's call stack and throw an error.

So I'd like to replace the infinite recursion with an infinite loop.  The problem with simply enclosing the relevant code in a `while(true)` block is that the loop won't wait for the "end" event in `d3.layout.force()` to fire before continuing on to the next iteration of the loop.  Thus my questions are:

1. Does Javascript provide syntax for "wait until a specific event is triggered before moving on to the next iteration in a loop"?
2. Is there a more d3ish way to get what I want?

Comment: Have you actually seen a call stack issue with this code?  The `end` function is async and should get it's own callstack.  In fact, I just ran 75,000 iterations of the above code (simplified) and had neither memory or call stack troubles...

Comment: @Mark I was getting a call stack error in a much more complex version of the code above, and admittedly I just assumed it was due to infinite recursion.  If this isn't the problem, would you mind explaining what's going on under the hood, perhaps as an answer?

Comment: I'd agree. I don't see any infinite recursion here. If you share an example that actually does have your call stack error, we can probably help figure out where it's coming from.